# Why getaddrinfo("localhost", "600", &hints, &listp) creates two socket address which are 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1?

Tags: sockets, networking, port

Could anyone explain to me in the code below, why does:

- `getaddrinfo("localhost", "600", &hints, &listp)` create two socket addresses which are `0.0.0.0` and `127.0.0.1`?

  **output:**

  ```
  IP address: 0.0.0.0   
  sin_family: 30  
  sin_port: 600 

  IP address: 127.0.0.1
  sin_family: 2
  sin_port: 600

  listenfd: -1
  ```
- `getaddrinfo("localhost", "6060", &hints, &listp)` create one socket address `0.0.0.0`?

  **output:**

  ```
  IP address: 0.0.0.0
  sin_family: 30  
  sin_port: 6060   

  listenfd: 5
  ```
- `getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "6060", &hints, &listp)` create one socket address `127.0.0.1`, which binded to `listenfd` 3?

  **output:**

  ```
  IP address: 127.0.0.1   
  sin_family: 2
  sin_port: 6060   

  listenfd: 3
  ```
- `getaddrinfo(NULL, "6060", &hints, &listp)` create one socket address `0.0.0.0`, which binded to `listenfd` 4?

  **output:**

  ```
  IP address: 0.0.0.0
  sin_family: 30
  sin_port: 6060

  listenfd: 4
  ```

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define LISTENQ 10

int open_listenfd()
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *listp, *p;
    int s, listenfd, optval=1;

    // Get a list of potential server addresses
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    // hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE | AI_ADDRCONFIG; 
    hints.ai_flags |= AI_NUMERICSERV;

    s = getaddrinfo(NULL, "600", &hints, &listp);
    if (s != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Walk the list for one that we can bind to
    for(p = listp; p; p = p->ai_next) {

        struct sockaddr_in *addr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
        char *m = inet_ntoa(addr_in->sin_addr);
        printf("IP address: %s\n", m);
        printf("sin_family: %i\n", addr_in->sin_family);
        printf("sin_port: %i\n", htons(addr_in->sin_port)); 

        // Create a socket descriptor
        if ((listenfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol))<0)
            continue;
    
        // Eliminates "Address already in use"l error from bind
        setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void *)&optval, sizeof(int));

        // Bind the descriptor to the address
        if(bind(listenfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == 0)
            break;
        close(listenfd); // Bind failed, try the next
    }
    // Clean up
    freeaddrinfo(listp);
    if(!p) // No address worked
        return -1;

    // Make it a listening socket ready to accept connectionn request
    if(listen(listenfd, LISTENQ) < 0) {
        close(listenfd);
        return -1;
    }
    return listenfd;
}

int main() {
    int listenfd;
    listenfd = open_listenfd();
    printf("listenfd: %i\n", listenfd);
}
```

Isn't `getaddrinfo("localhost", "600", &hints, &listp)` supposed to create a socket address that has **only one** IP address `127.0.0.0`, even if port 600 cannot be used for some reason?

Shouldn't `getaddrinfo("localhost", "6060", &hints, &listp)` AND `getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "6060", &hints, &listp)` produce the same result since `localhost` refers to `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Thank you very much for you explanation! Remy. I think what you said explained the last 2 cases. But what about the first 2 cases: shouldn't getaddrinfo() only convert "localhost" into socket address structure that corresponding to the loopback IP address 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0? Because I think getaddrinfo() only convert "NULL" into socket address structure that corresponding to the 0.0.0.0 which refers to all IPv4 addresses.

Comment: I updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is assuming that all entries in the list are `AF_INET`/`sockaddr_in` addresses only, but you are not setting a value for `hints.ai_family`, so your `memset()` causes it to be set to `AF_UNSPEC` (0), which gives `getaddrinfo()` freedom to return other address types than just `AF_INET`.

As such, you need to check `p->ai_family` before casting `p->ai_addr` to the corresponding `sockaddr_...` type. The output code you have so far is only legal when `p->ai_family` is `AF_INET` and not something else, like say `AF_INET6`.

Note that in your example output, some entries say `sin_family: 30`, which is definitely not `AF_INET` (2). `0.0.0.0` is only legal for `AF_INET`. On some systems, like Apple, address family 30 is `AF_INET6`. But `AF_INET6` is defined differently on other systems (ie, it is 10 on Linux, and 23 on Windows, etc). So, this is why you need to be careful with handling address families correctly, and use the correct `sockaddr_...` struct for each family.

For example, when querying `getaddrinfo()` using `NULL` or `"localhost"`, and  `hints.ai_family` is `AF_UNSPEC`, you can (and likely are) receiving the `AF_INET6` loopback IP `::1`, but the code you have shown would display it incorrectly as `0.0.0.0` instead, since you would be formatting a display string for the 32-bit `sockaddr_in6::sin6_flowinfo` field (which is likely 0) instead of the 128-bit `sockaddr_in6::sin6_addr` field.

If you want to force only `AF_INET` output, then you need to set `hints.ai_family` to `AF_INET` when calling `getaddrinfo()`.  Otherwise, you need to update your loop code to handle other address types that `getaddrinfo()` may give you, not just `AF_INET` alone, eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define LISTENQ 10

int open_listenfd()
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *listp, *p;
    int s, listenfd, optval = 1;
    char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN+1];

    // Get a list of potential server addresses
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // or AF_INET, AF_INET6, etc
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE | AI_ADDRCONFIG | AI_NUMERICSERV;

    s = getaddrinfo(NULL, "600", &hints, &listp);
    if (s != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Walk the list showing all IPs that were found
    for(p = listp; p; p = p->ai_next) {

        printf("ai_family: %i\n", p->ai_family);

        switch (p->ai_family) {
            case AF_INET: {
                struct sockaddr_in *addr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *) p->ai_addr;
                printf("IP address: %s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(addr_in->sin_addr), ipstr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN));
                printf("Port: %i\n", ntohs(addr_in->sin_port)); 
            }
            break;

            case AF_INET6: {
                struct sockaddr_in6 *addr_in6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) p->ai_addr;
                printf("IP address: %s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(addr_in6->sin6_addr), ipstr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN));
                printf("Port: %i\n", ntohs(addr_in6->sin_port)); 
            }
            break;

            //...
        }

        printf("\n"); 
    }

    // Walk the list looking for one that we can bind to
    for(p = listp; p; p = p->ai_next) {

        // Create a socket descriptor
        if ((listenfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) < 0)
            continue;
    
        // Eliminates "Address already in use" error from bind
        setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void *)&optval, sizeof(int));

        // Bind the descriptor to the address
        if (bind(listenfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == 0)
            break;

        close(listenfd); // Bind failed, try the next
    }

    if (p) {
        // TODO: display which one was picked...
    }

    // Clean up
    freeaddrinfo(listp);
    if (!p) // No address worked
        return -1;

    // Make it a listening socket ready to accept connection request
    if (listen(listenfd, LISTENQ) < 0) {
        close(listenfd);
        return -1;
    }

    return listenfd;
}

int main() {
    int listenfd = open_listenfd();
    printf("listenfd: %i\n", listenfd);
}
```

Comment: OMG! You're awesome! Thank you very much for you detailed explanation, your time and effort, you explained so well. Last night, I finally realized that 1) "localhost"and NULL can be translated into IPv4 and IPv6 address by getaddrinfor() if I don't set ai_family in hints. 2) "localhost" will be ::1 in IPv6, 127.0.0.1 in IPv4. NULL will be :: in IPv6 , 0.0. 0.0 in IPv4.